# mysql - query to lookup multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single mysql table. Query should lookup prev_id multiple times till the insertimestamp is between cuurent and previous week and get the rows to columns.

```
 ID | inserttimestamp| prev_id  | category  
 -----------------------------
 5  | 2017-06-08     |     4    | Level456
 4  | 2017-06-05     |     3    | Level241
 3  | 2017-05-31     |     2    | Level456
 2  | 2017-05-28     |     1    | Level247
 1  | 2017-05-27     |          | Level231
```

The result should be something like this,

```
 ID | inserttimestamp| prev_id  | category    | id1  | id1_category  | id2   | id2_category   |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5  | 2017-06-08     |     4    | Level456    |  4   |  Level 241    |   3   |   Level456     |
```

In this case as you see it stopped to id 3  because id 2 and 1 are not falling under previous week.

Use Case: To find out how many level upgrade/downgrade happened since previous week

For the above records its  Levelupgrade - 1 , LevelDowngrade -1

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in SQL, you need a procedural language that can loop.

Comment: What is your use case for this, if I may ask? I feel like there may be a better solution for what you want to achieve

Comment: Use case is to find out how many level upgrade/downgrade happened since previous week.

Comment: @Barmar . . . It *can* be done in SQL.  In ANSI standard SQL at that.  Just not in *MySQL*.